# How to explicitly specify the type of http request to prisma queries

Tags: next.js, middleware, prisma, web-development-server, rate-limiting

I'm building a NextJs 14 web app. I'm using server actions to get the data from the database in a client component. When checking the network request. I see that prisma is making a POST request instead of GET. How can i ensure that It should make a GET request?

**The problem I'm trying to solve is to rate limit the number of POST request from the client component. To solve this I'm using NextJs middleware by using @upstash/ratelimit and @vercel/kv**

When I open the page it sends 4 POST requests (haven't figured it out why it it sending 4 instead of 2) that is considered by the middleware as a POST request and it reduces the POST request count for a period of time.

Middleware File:

```js
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { Ratelimit } from '@upstash/ratelimit';
import { kv } from '@vercel/kv';


const ratelimit = new Ratelimit({
  redis: kv,
  //allow  5 requests from the same IP in 10 seconds
  limiter: Ratelimit.slidingWindow(5, '10 s'),
});

// Define which routes you want to rate limit
export const config = {
  matcher: "/((?!api|_next|fonts|examples|dashboard|not-found|[\\w-]+\\.\\w+).*)/",
}

export default async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  // You could alternatively limit based on user ID or similar
  const ip = request.ip ?? '127.0.0.1';
  console.log("IP: ", ip);
  if(request.method === 'POST') {
    // console.log("Request: ", request);
    const { success, pending, limit, reset, remaining } = await ratelimit.limit(
      ip
    )
    console.log("success: ", success);
    console.log("remaining: ", remaining);
      
      
    return success
      ? NextResponse.next()
      : NextResponse.redirect("/");
  }
  return NextResponse.next();
}
```

Here is the component:

```js
"use client";

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useRouter, useParams } from "next/navigation";
import {
  getAnsweredQuestionsByUsername,
  getCreatorPageDetails,
} from "../actions/actions";
import { UserProps, Username } from "./types";
import Image from "next/image";
import UserForm from "@/components/UserForm";
import { Question } from "../dashboard/types";

const UserPage = () => {
  const params = useParams();
  const router = useRouter();
  const username: Username = params.username;
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [recipient, setRecipient] = useState<UserProps>({});
  const [answeredQuestions, setAnsweredQuestions] = useState<Question[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getUserData() {
      const recipentDetails = await getCreatorPageDetails(username as string);
      const answeredQuestions = await getAnsweredQuestionsByUsername(
        username as string
      );
      if (!recipentDetails) {
        router.replace("/not-found");
      } else {
        setRecipient(recipentDetails);
        setAnsweredQuestions(answeredQuestions as Question[]);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    }
    getUserData();
  }, []);
```

Here are the actions:

```js
export async function getCreatorPageDetails(username : string) {
  try {
    const user = await prisma.user.findFirst({
      where: {
        username: username as string,
      },
    });
    return user;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Couldn't find user", error);
  }
}

export async function getAnsweredQuestionsByUsername(username: string) {
  try {
    const answeredQuestions = await prisma.question.findMany({
      include: {
        answer: true,
      },
      orderBy: {
        createdAt: 'desc',
      },
      where: {
        isAnswered: true,
      }
    })

    return answeredQuestions;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error getting questions", error);
    return {
      error: "Error getting questions for username"
    }
    
  }
}
```

I tried to find a way to somehow make the prisma queries as GET but didn't find any solutions for that. If there is another way to do this. I would appreciate the response.

Answer (score 0):

Found this in official Nextjs documentation:

> Behind the scenes, actions use the POST method, and only this HTTP method can invoke them.

Src: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions-and-mutations